# Is it possible to run android espresso ui tests from the terminal on multiple devices one after another?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm trying to run my ui tests on at least 2 phones but it can't be simultaneously, they have to run after each other. So when Phone 1 has completed the test run, Phone 2 begin its test run.

I'm looking for a command similar to `./gradlew cAT` but not simultaneously. An alternative would be to specify which phone the tests should run on. The reason is I need to be able to run the tests through GitLab CI.

Is it possible to do this from the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would likely be to create a script that calls your gradle task with each specific device serial set beforehand. This is theoretical, but should work.

```
ANDROID_SERIAL=<firstDeviceSerial> ./gradlew <yourCommand>
ANDROID_SERIAL=<secondDeviceSerial> ./gradlew <yourCommand>
```

Answer (score 0):

They introduced the notion of pools of devices. These are now responsible for running a test suite instead of each device running the suite separately. That has two side effects:

- infinite scaling: your tests can speed up by as many devices and emulators as you can dedicate to your CI box.
- because test suites now get scheduled to run on a pool, not all tests will run on all devices. For that reason, we also introduced a way to create a pool per device, which offers full coverage (a.k.a. Spoon-mode) but typically takes longer, so we run it on a nightly basis. It works out-of-the-box, without any code changes.

A few similar tools:

[composer](https://github.com/gojuno/composer#optional)

[marathon](https://malinskiy.github.io/marathon/doc/configuration.html)

[fork](https://github.com/shazam/fork)